# Define php function and use without ()

Tags: php

Is it possible to define a function  and use without ()?

Like `require("a.php")` and `require "a.php"`.

```
function getNameById($id){}; /*and use it like*/ $id = getNameById "1";
```

Thanks.

Comment: and why would you do that? it's not like PHP needs to be compressed like JS.

Comment: It wouldn't really benefit from looking like VB6, either.

Comment: I have an function that loads classes and namespaces.
Like import("a.b.c");
I want to do like import "a.b.c"; or import a.b.c. Like in Java or using  a.b.c; like .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have mention, `require` and for example `echo`, `isset` and `empty` are language constructs. Which means that it is built into the php core.

The only way you can create your own constructs is by writing a php extension in C. So to answer your question, not in pure php.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Mattias..
I will try  to do it.

Answer (score 8):

No, it isn't. `require` is a language construct, just like `echo`, `print`, `include`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible. `require` is a language construct; *not* a function.

Answer (score 2):

`require` is a special language construct, not a function, and no, it's not possible.